# So I'm a moderator now?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, moderators

Just... what?

Here's a recent answer of mine:

[image]

And here's my profile at the moment:

[image]

Ok... but the problem here is no other mod capabilities appear to be available to me. No tools, for example. And the same doesn't show up on the iPad app when I try that.

Comment: I don't see it when I go on your page.

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you see this in incognito mode or on a different profile? I don't see you as a moderator anywhere. http://i.stack.imgur.com/l4YHc.png

Comment: @Gilles Chrome 39 (stable not Canary), yes and yes.

Comment: By the way, your image reveals your real name and email address, you may want to obscure that and request the original to be scrubbed.

Comment: I don't see it on Chrome 39.0.2171.99.

Comment: @Gilles I don't particularly care, I can deal with the odd strange email

Comment: Meh, if you were a moderator your profile page would look very different. Moderators see some different information, and have additional links available. An issue that gave you 'the diamond' without giving you the moderator tools, is... unlikely.

Comment: Which CSS files are you getting? You should be getting http://cdn.sstatic.net/worldbuildingmeta/all.css?v=1ab6dba67ae0 whereas moderators would be getting http://cdn.sstatic.net/moderator.css?v=492416cdadf8 as well.

Comment: @rolfl Clearly I'm **not** a mod, but I want to know why that diamond appeared at all.

Comment: @Gilles Just the first.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - My concern was more about a non-mod having access to moderation tools in general. Once I realized that this is just a cosmetic issue, and not a problem that could lead to more serious harm, then I quit caring as much. I figure someome is just pranking you, or something (you pranking us...?), but I don't have enough information to give an actual answer. My concern ends at the point where this is revealed to be purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no way for you to get the diamond without someone with developer access doing the following:

- Giving it to you through developer tools
- Manually executing a query that essentially does what the tool would

Whenever someone is promoted to moderator by appointment or election, an entry is made in a user history table indicating that your access changed, and the name of the developer that did it:

[image: We log all kinds of stuff]

There is *no* such user history event for you on the main or meta site. I checked, just to make sure someone didn't accidentally click on the wrong profile while granting access.

In order for you to have a diamond, there *must also* be a corresponding history event. While I'm going to look, I can't think of any possible bug or scenario that would end up with a diamond / moderator status next to your name, *without* access to the tools, as seen from your profile screen shot. So that basically rules out either possible scenario:

- You weren't given access by someone that has access to the developer tools
- We don't have a rogue developer manually running queries to avoid logging of diamond grants

Unless there's some information that you didn't include in your report, I'm sticking this right behind Big Bird in my filing cabinet ;)

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to call shenanigans.

If you compare the flair from a moderator on another beta site:

[image]

with your's from the screenshot you posted

[image]

the diamond looks to be further away from the name than usual. Plus there is other information and links that are available to a moderator on their profile which aren't visible on your screenshot either.

I'm not going to even guess how you did it, but I don't think you are really seeing this on the site.

Comment: And in case someone ways "maybe it's different on some sites", look at Jon's usercard in the edit to the question.

Comment: I went to a different beta site deliberately as they all use the same CSS. It's closer on all sites, but with the different fonts used on graduated sites it can be hard to tell.

Comment: I wouldn't bother wasting time if I knew why I was seeing it - either SE went wrong or my computer did, but I don't see how in either case.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Not something on our end. Check your browser extensions, etc.

Comment: @AnnaLear Can't find anything... Strange.